# How to include a file within the library into a page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
I tried like 
$this->obj->load->library('phpmailer');
$this->obj->load->library('phpmailer/class.phpmailer');
```

But it causes php error.Please suggest a solution.

Comment: from where did you get `$this->obj->load` ?

Comment: @Sujathan whr you put that phpmailer.php file ???

Comment: @Mihai Iorga How can I increase or how to accept an answer from the guys?Is there any link or button to accept an answer?

Comment: hi all now it seems fixed.I removed the second line of code.thanks all.

Comment: @SujathanNedumparambu, yes at every answer under answer score you received you have an Check mark (**✔**), when your problem is solved you have to give credits to the one who helped you

Answer (score 0):

create a custom loader for the same. You can find how to extend database classes in codeigniter tutorials on the github site of codeigniter, from that tutorial you can get a hint of whats going on and then you can implement how to create custom library loader well if not you can use "core" folder, it is the autoloader for the libraries. check the documentation for codeigniter.

Check these links:

[Extending db drivers](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Extending-Database-Drivers)

[Core classes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the phpmailer library and put this instruction

```
include('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
```

Your phpmailer and folder phpmailer should reside in the library folder.Your phpmailer folder should contain the file class.phpmailer.php. Now call it

```
$this->load->library('phpmailer ');
```

Done!